# Problems creating greatest common divisor in java

Tags: java

I'm following the logic that I was given for this calculation, but it seems to only give me an endless loop. Can I get some help?

The logic I was supposed to use is :

The formula for finding the greatest common divisor of two positive integers x and y
follows the Euclidean algorithm as follows:
1. Subtract x from y repeatedly until y < x.
2. Swap the values of x and y.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until x = 0.
4. y is the greatest common divisor of the two numbers.

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package project4.pkg3;

/**
 *
 * @author LMFS
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project43 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int numOne, numTwo;
        String c = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String another = "y";
        while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
            numOne = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
            numTwo = sc.nextInt();

            c = doMath(numOne, numTwo);

            //use static method here.
            System.out.println("Greatest common divisor: " + c);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Continue? (y/n): ");
            another = sc.next();
        }

    }

    public static String doMath(int numOne, int numTwo) {
        while (numOne != 0) {
            System.out.println("//debugging line 48: " + numOne);
            while (numTwo > numOne) {
                numTwo -= numOne;
                System.out.println("//debugging line 52: " + numTwo);
            }
            while (numOne > numTwo) {
                numOne -= numTwo;
                System.out.println("//debugging line 57: " + numOne);
            }
        }
        return Integer.toString(numTwo);
    }
}
```

EDIT: this is solved. I changed the static method to this:

```
    public static int egcd(int a, int b) {
if (a == 0)
    return b;

while (b != 0) {
    if (a > b)
        a = a - b;
    else
        b = b - a;
    }

return a;
}
```

Comment: If you've solved your problem, create a new answer with the solution and accept it.  This will indicate to the rest of the community that your question is answered.

Comment: The OP hasn't solved the problem yet.  Just wait until they test their solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the algorithm the way you've implemented it, either `numOne` or `numTwo` could reach zero first.  But if `numTwo` gets to zero before `numOne` does, then your second nested loop inside `doMath` will never exit, because the condition will always be true.

One way you could fix this would be to add

```
if (numTwo == 0) {
    return numOne;
}
```

in between the two nested loops.

Also, I recommend dropping the `Integer.toString` part from the return of this method, and just having it return an `int` or an `Integer` instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: I always thought that Euclidean algorithm breaks when the numbers are equal to each other. The found number is GCD.

Also, I think you don't need several loops in main calculation loop. Try to replace them with `if` statements. So, it will be easier to find the error (try to run your program with numbers 1 and 1)

Comment: No, the Euclidean algorithm doesn't break if the numbers are equal.  The first subtraction just yields zero, so the GCD is the original number.  This fits the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Make this fixes in method `doMath`:

```
// Until one of the numbers divides by other
while (numOne % numTwo != 0 && numTwo % numOne != 0) {
```

instead of:

```
while (numOne != 0) {
```

And before return make this change

```
int result = numOne / numTwo == 0 ? numOne : numTwo;
return Integer.toString(result);
```

On Console  I got following results:

```
Enter first number: 
14
Enter second number: 
49
... some debugging log
Greatest common divisor: 7
```